# Unable to continuously send data between tcpserver and tcpclient in java

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

My TCP Client does not seems to be able to receive the data send from server after the connection is being accepted by the server.

I made the client initiate the connection, and I like it to work in this way.

```
loop:
client --> Server;
client <-- Server;
```

I am new to Java `TCP` socket programming, could somebody please enlighten me on how to make them work properly. Thanks and Appreciate help given in advance.

TCP Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Message:");
            sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            if(!sentence.equals("exit"))
            {
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); //It does not receive any data from server.
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
            }
            else
            {
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                clientSocket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TCP Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class TCPServer
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        String clientSentence;
        String serverSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        Socket connectionSocket;
        connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true)
        {
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            if(!clientSentence.equals("exit\n"))
            {
                System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
                System.out.println("Message:");
                serverSentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                outToClient.writeBytes(serverSentence); //able to send, but client is not receiving.
            }
            else
            {
                connectionSocket.close();
                welcomeSocket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems wrong too: `if(!clientSentence.equals("exit\n"))`, readLine won't return \n.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the data:

```
outToClient.writeBytes(serverSentence); //able to send, but client is not receiving.
outToClient.flush();
```

Comment: I have tried your method. However, it does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

After `outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');` do `outToServer.flush();`

After `outToClient.writeBytes(serverSentence + '\n');` do `outToClient.flush();`

Comment: I have tried your method, but its not working. I tried printing filler statements, it seems that server is able to send, but client is still not receiving.

Comment: @BetaTester Your message sending sequence should be: 1) Client sends data to server 2) Server receives data from client 3) Server sends data back to client.

Comment: If you run my code, it is already behaving in this sequence isn't it?

Comment: @BetaTester Try to use same I/O Streams at both ends for sockets. For example if you are using `BufferedReader` for reading from `socket` stream than use `BufferedWriter`  for writing to `socket` stream.

Answer (score 0):

In the client you are closing the socket after sending data to the server. You need to keep it open.

```
while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Message:");
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        if(!sentence.equals("exit"))
        {
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
            modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); //It does not receive any data from server.
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        }
        else
        {
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
            clientSocket.close(); //socket gets closed. Reopen it on the server side or remove that line
            break;
        }
    }
```